# PHP/SOAP response dataset empty

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm attempting to get data from a Web Service using PHP/SOAP and the response dataset is always empty. I believe that the issue lays in how I set the dsParams parameter.

[This is the Web Service URL](https://www.maxhire.net/MaxHireAPI/UserServices.asmx?wsdl)

If I use SoapUI and send this request:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://www.maxhire.net/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <max:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <max:DatabaseName>Name</max:DatabaseName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <max:SecurityKey>Key</max:SecurityKey>
      </max:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults>
         <max:strProcName>JobPostings</max:strProcName>
         <max:dsParams>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Table">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="ParamName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="ParamValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
         </max:dsParams>
      </max:ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get a desired result.

Each web method that is called using SOAP must pass appropriate security credentials. These credentials must be specified in the SOAP header as DatabaseName and SecurityKey. This part is working correctly.

According to the documentation:

About dsParams

A few things to note about the dsParams dataset that you must pass to use either of these functions (*e.g. ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults*):

1. Even if you have no parameters, you must pass a dataset object that contains one initialized tabled.
2. If you do have parameters, you must have two columns in that table that are named “ParamName” and “ParamValue”.
3. Each parameter should be its own row in the table with its name in the first column and value in the second.

Note: I do not have parameters.

Below is an example of one of many ways I’ve attempted to approach this task. It is the closest that I can get without getting errors.

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.maxhire.net/MaxHireAPI/UserServices.asmx?wsdl',array('trace' => TRUE));

$header = new SoapHeader(
        'http://www.maxhire.net/',
        'AuthHeader',array(
                'DatabaseName' => 'Name', 
                'SecurityKey'  => 'Key'
            ),
        false
        );

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

try {
    $jobs = new stdClass();
    $jobs->strProcName = 'JobPostings';
    $jobs->NewDataSet = new stdClass();
    $jobs->NewDataSet->Table = new stdClass();
    $jobs->NewDataSet->Table->ParamName = '';
    $jobs->NewDataSet->Table->ParamValue = '';

    $result = $client->ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults($jobs);

    echo "<pre>\n";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>\n";
}
catch(SoapFault $soapfault){
    echo "<pre>\n";
    var_dump($soapfault);
    echo "</pre>\n";
}
```

The following is the response that I get:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
  ["ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResultsResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
    ["schema"]=>
    string(323) "<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>"
    ["any"]=>
    string(127) "<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>"
  }
}


echo "Request:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "<br />\n";

Request:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.maxhire.net/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:AuthHeader>
            <ns1:DatabaseName>Name</ns1:DatabaseName>
            <ns1:SecurityKey>Key</ns1:SecurityKey>
        </ns1:AuthHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults>
            <ns1:strProcName>JobPostings</ns1:strProcName>
        </ns1:ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResults>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br />\n";

Response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResultsResponse xmlns="http://www.maxhire.net/">
            <ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResultsResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
            </ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResultsResult>
        </ExecuteCustomStoredProcedureGetResultsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you print a `$client->__getLastRequest()` and `$client->__getLastResponse()` !

Comment: @Anas above I've added the __getLastRequest() and __getLastResponse() results.

Comment: Did you manage to get the response?